# How to use `ln -s` to change between R Versions on Mac?

Tags: r

An [RStudio support article](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200486138-Using-Different-Versions-of-R) says that you can alternate between different R Versions on your mac if you "update the R.framework/Versions/Current directory alias directly using `ln -s`"

How exactly do you use `ln -s` to change between R Versions?

When I type into my terminal `ls -l /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/` I see:

```
total 0
drwxrwxr-x  6 root  admin  192 Jan 15 09:04 3.3
drwxrwxr-x  6 root  admin  192 Jun  5 16:36 3.5
drwxrwxr-x  3 root  admin   96 Jun  5 16:36 3.6
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin    3 Jun  5 16:36 Current -> 3.5
```

But I am unsure of how `ln -s` can be used to alternate between these R versions. I have currently "switched" from 3.6 to 3.5 by redownloading 3.5. A practice I would like to avoid.

Into my terminal I typed `rm /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/Current` which did remove the existing Current. And then on separate attempts I have typed `ln -s 3.6 /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/Current`

This changed the symlink

```
ls -l /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/ 
total 0 
drwxrwxr-x 6 root admin 192 Jan 15 09:04 3.3 
drwxrwxr-x 6 root admin 192 Jun 5 16:36 3.5 
drwxrwxr-x 4 root admin 128 Jun 6 09:09 3.6 
lrwxr-xr-x 1 joepowers admin 3 Jun 6 09:15 Current -> 3.6
```

But when I type R.version in the console I get back 3.4.3

Next I tried

```
ln -s /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6 /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/Current
ls -l /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/
total 0
drwxrwxr-x  6 root       admin  192 Jan 15 09:04 3.3
drwxrwxr-x  3 root       admin   96 Jun  6 09:21 3.5
drwxrwxr-x  7 root       admin  224 Jun  6 09:21 3.6
lrwxr-xr-x  1 joepowers  admin   44 Jun  6 09:23 Current -> /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6
```

But typing `R.version` in the console still returns 3.4.3 even after restarting RStudio.

Comment: Do you have other versions of R installed from source (for example via homebrew?). The next section of that article says that by default R looks for R in (in order) `/usr/bin/R`, `/usr/bin/local/R` and `/opt/local/bin/R` before defaulting to the versions in `R.framework`. Are there versions of R in any of those folders?

Comment: What do you get when you type `R.home()` in the console?

Answer (score 7):

`ln -s` creates a symlink, also known as an alias (on  Mac) or shortcut (in Windows).

When it starts R, RStudio loads the version of R in `/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/Current`.

From that view you posted above, we can see that you have 3 versions of R installed (`3.3`, `3.5`, and `3.6`). `/Current` is actually a symlink to `3.5` (that's what the `Current -> 3.5` means).

If you want to change this, you  need to:

1. Go to the appropriate directory with: `cd /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/`
2. Delete the existing `Current` symlink with: `rm Current`

   - `rm` will delete symlinks to directories but will not delete directories themselves
3. Create a new symlink to version 3.6 with: `ln -s 3.6 Current`